# Tkinter drawing on canvas is delayed

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter, drawing

I am new to tkinter and trying to make a basic drawing app. However, when I move my cursor around, it will sometimes suddenly stop drawing, and then only show the finished line several seconds later. This is shown here.

https://www.youtube.com/edit?video_referrer=watch&video_id=_g8n55V6qPQ

Is this lag? My laptop runs fine otherwise, and it can even 'lag' on the first go (i.e. before there are any other objects on the canvas). If it is just lag, what sort of workarounds do I have in making my python drawing app?

This is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.title("Note Taking")

can_width = 800
can_height = 800
canvas = Canvas(root, width=can_width, height=can_height, bg='white')
canvas.pack(padx=20, pady=20)

class g():
    points = []
    user_line = None
    drawing = False
    t = 0

def leftClick(event):
    g.points = []
    g.user_line = None
    g.drawing = True
    g.points.append(event.x)
    g.points.append(event.y)

def leftMove(event):
    # Print out an increasing number: t, so I can see it in the output
    print(g.t)
    g.t+=1

    if g.drawing: 
        g.points.append(event.x)
        g.points.append(event.y)
        if g.user_line == None:
            g.user_line = canvas.create_line(g.points, width=4, smooth=1)
        else:
            canvas.coords(g.user_line, g.points)

def leftRelease(event):
    g.points = []
    g.user_line = None


canvas.bind('<Button-1>', leftClick)
canvas.bind('<B1-Motion>', leftMove)
canvas.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', leftRelease)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Don't use `print`. [Print slows down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52354963/using-print-in-loop-slows-down-the-loop). Try to optimise your code. This will help.

Comment: This bug happened before I used print. How can I optimise my code? It seems pretty bare bones to me right now.